# Soft Delete with Foreign key

Tags: laravel

I am a newbies in laravel and currently is doing laravel project. I have a question,is it possible if i want to apply soft delete for one table but the id is foreign key in another table?

This is my database schema

```
 Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->string('role');
        $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->foreignId('current_team_id')->nullable();
        $table->string('profile_photo_path', 2048)->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
    });'
```

User Model

```
 protected $fillable = [
    'name',
    'email',
    'password',
    'role'
];
protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];
public function grp()
{
return $this->belongsToMany(Group::class);
}
```

Controller

```
public function creatorList(Request $request)
{
    $user=User::with('grp')->get();
    if($request->has('view_deleted'))
    {
        $user = User::onlyTrashed()->get();
    }

    
    return view("admin.creatorlist",['user'=>$user]);
}

 public function delete($id)
{
    User::find($id)->delete();

    return back()->with('success', 'User Deleted successfully');
}

public function restore($id)
{
    User::withTrashed()->find($id)->restore();

    return back()->with('success', 'User Restore successfully');
}

public function restore_all()
{
    User::onlyTrashed()->restore();

    return back()->with('success', 'All User Restored successfully');
}
```

creatorlist.blade.php blade file

```
@if(session()->has('success'))
  <div class="alert alert-success">
    {{ session()->get('success') }}
      </div>
      @endif
      <br>
      @include('flash-message')
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 stretch-card">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
              <p class="card-title">Group creator list</p>
              @if(request()->has('view_deleted'))

            <a href="{{ route('post.creatorList') }}" class="btn btn-info btn-sm">View All User</a>

            <a href="{{ route('post.restore_all') }}" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Restore All</a>

            @else

            <a href="{{ route('post.creatorList', ['view_deleted' => 'DeletedRecords']) }}" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">View Deleted User</a>

            @endif
              <div class="table-responsive">
                <table id="recent-purchases-listing" class="table">
                  <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>No.</th>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Group</th>
                        <th></th>
                        <th></th>
                    </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody>
                  @if(count($user) > 0)
                      @foreach($user as $user)
                      @if($user->role == '2')
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{$user->id}}</td>
                        <td>{{$user->name}}</td>
                        <td>
                        
                        @foreach($user->grp as $group)
                        <ul>
                        <li>{{$group->groupName}}</li>
                        </ul> 
                        @endforeach
                  
                        </td>
                        <td>
                        @if(request()->has('view_deleted'))

                        <a href="{{ route('post.restore', $user->id) }}" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Restore</a>
                        @else
                        <form method="post" action="{{ route('post.delete', $user->id) }}">
                                            @csrf
                                            <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE" />
                                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Delete</button>
                                        </form>@endif</td>
```

This is web.php

```
Route::get("/listmember",[adminControl::class,"creatorList"])->name('post.creatorList');
Route::delete('post/{id}', [adminControl::class, 'delete'])->name('post.delete');
Route::get('post/restore/one/{id}', [adminControl::class, 'restore'])->name('post.restore');
Route::get('post/restore_all', [adminControl::class, 'restore_all'])->name('post.restore_all');
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Yes, soft delete sets the `deleted_at` column value to a timestamp, like `2022-04-07 12:00:00`, but doesn't remove the record from the DB. If that row's ID is used as a FK elsewhere, it will still be in the database. You might need to expand your question a little more if you need more information.

Comment: It shows error (SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1451 Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails)

Comment: You'll need to [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71785345/edit) and include your database schema, migration, model, and code you're calling to do the delete. That error would not be triggered by performing a `delete` operation on a Soft-Deleted model, so you might have missed something in your setup.

Comment: i already edit my question :)

Comment: You're missing `$table->softDeletes()` from your Migration: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/migrations#column-method-softDeletes, and you're missing the `use SoftDeletes` trait on your model: Add `use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;` to the top, then `use SoftDeletes;` after `class User extends ...` in `User.php`